# Show P(A^c) ⊈ P(U) − P(A) without using a counterexample.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

This is what I have:

Suppose $x ∈ P(A^c)$.

$x ∈ P(A^c) ⇒ x ⊆ A^c$

$⇒ x ⊆ U - A$

$⇒ x ∈ P(U – A)$

but how do I know that $x \notin P(U) - P(A)$?

Also, doesn't $x ⊆ U - A$ imply $x ∈ P(U) - P(A)$?

Comment: If $P$ means powerset, then $P(U) - P(A)$ removed one important set that exists in $P(A^c)$.

Comment: For the first part, if $U$ is your universal set (that is $A$ is a subset of $U$), then we have $A^c=U-A$ by definition, so $P(A^c)=P(U-A)$.

Comment: A certain set is contained in *every* power set. Which one? What does mean for the left-hand side and the right-hand side of your non-inclusion?

Answer (score 1):

> doesn't $x ⊆ U - A$ imply $x ∈ P(U) - P(A)$?

Not quite. $x \in P(U) - P(A)$ means that $x$ is a subset of $U$ ($x\in P(U)$) but not a subset of $A$ ($x\notin P(A)$).

On the other hand, $x\in P(U-A)$ means that $x$ is a subset of $U-A$. For example, as suggested by @peterwhy in comments, $\emptyset\in P(U-A)$ while $\emptyset \notin P(U)-P(A)$ (since $\emptyset \in P(A)$).

---

With the additional assumption that $U$ is finite with $m$ elements, we can see that, if $A$ has $n$ elements, then $P(U-A)$ has $2^{m-n}$ elements while $P(U)-P(A)$ has $2^m-2^n\neq 2^{m-n}$ elements.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $x = A \cap A^c$.

On one hand, $x \subseteq A^c$ so $x\in \mathcal P(A^c)$.

On the other hand, $x \subseteq A$, so $x \in \mathcal P(A)$ and $x\notin \mathcal P(U) - \mathcal P(A)$.

These two means there's at least some element of $\mathcal P(A^c)$ that's not in $\mathcal P(U) - \mathcal P(A)$:

$$\mathcal P(A^c) \not\subseteq \mathcal P(U) - \mathcal P(A)$$

(Of course, $x = A\cap A^c = \emptyset$)